# Do antilinear maps have adjoints?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T: H \to H$ be a continuous antilinear map on a Hilbert space $H$, that is $T(\alpha \xi + \eta)= \overline{\alpha} T \xi + T \eta$ for $\xi, \eta \in H$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. Does there exist an antilinear map $T^*: H \to H$ such that
$$\langle T^* \xi, \eta\rangle = \langle \xi, T\eta\rangle$$
for all $\xi, \eta \in H$ (or a variation on this).

I could try to mimique the "usual" proof for bounded linear maps, but maybe there is a smart way to avoid this kind of work by reducing to this case?

Comment: You mean $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ not $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.  An antilinear endomorphism of $H$ is the same as a linear endomorphism on $H\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}\overline{\mathbb{C}}$, so the result follows.

Comment: @user10354138 This is exactly the essence, I posted an answer that envelopes this idea in a fun way (in my opinion).

Comment: The adjoint of an anti-linear operator satisfies  $\langle T^* \xi, \eta\rangle = \langle T\eta, \xi\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $$\langle T^*\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle\xi, T\eta\rangle$$
cannot stand if $T,T^*$ are antilinear: the LHS is anti-linear on $\xi$ while RHS is linear on $\xi$. But if written as
$$\langle\eta,T^*\xi\rangle=\langle\xi,T\eta\rangle$$
then yeah, check this out:

Forget about scalar multiplication and inner product on $H$ for a bit and define new ones as $\lambda* x:=\bar{\lambda}\cdot x$ where in the RHS  the scalar multiplication is the old one. Also define $\langle x,y\rangle_2:=\langle y,x\rangle_H$ where the RHS inner product is the old one and note that $H$ endowed with the new scalar multiplication and $\langle-,-\rangle_2$ is a new Hilbert space. Also, $T$ is a bounded *linear* operator when seen acting from $H$ with the old structure towards $H$ with the new structure, thus it has an adjoint operator $T^*$ which acts from $H$ with the new structure to $H$ with the old structure, so
$$\langle Tx,y\rangle_2=\langle x,T^*y\rangle_H$$
i.e.
$$\langle y,Tx\rangle_H=\langle x,T^*y\rangle_H $$

which is what you want. Since $T^*$ is a linear operator for the new scalar multiplication, $T^*$ is antilinear for the original one.

Comment: Shouldn't $T$ be a linear map from the original $H$ to the new $H$? But anyway, it's right, we'll get $T^*$ from the new $H$ to the original $H$, which also means that it's antilinear on $H$.

Comment: @Berci woops. Yes, thanks for noticing I will correct it. The proof doesn't get destroyed though as we can take adjoints of operators with different domain and target spaces, righr?

Comment: Yes, it's still a valid argument.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Thanks for this wonderful answer. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @user839372 glad i could help